# SQL server slower on faster machine

Tags: sql-server, performance, windows-server-2012

We have two servers with the same operating system (Windows Server 2012 Standard, Microsoft Windows NT 6.2 (9200)) and same SQL server (12.0.2000.8), and the database is restored from first server on second.

First machine:
Inter(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5420 @ 2.5GHz 2.49 GHz
Ram: 8.00 GB

Second machine:
Inter(R) Xeon(TM) CPU  3GHz 2.99 GHz(2 processors)
Ram: 23.0 GB

Every query that we tried is **slower(2.5X) on second machine** than on first.
Queries were executed from SQL Server Management Studio (from each machine) and they have the same execution plan.

Already tried to update statistics (EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN') on second machine but it resulted in minor increase of speed (maybe 10%).

Does somebody have any advice what to do ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: How about the storage subsystem? Are the drivers updated? Is it a VM or bare metal?

Comment: Try to force the query to use single thread. (MAXDOP = 1). You should compare the query generated on both machines.

Comment: In addition to the plan, compare your IO reads (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`), also check where the time is being spent (`SET STATISTICS TIME ON`). How many tests have you done on each machine?

Comment: @GarethD, when i run query on first server i got in Messages tab:
Table 'Table'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7582, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 5497, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 686 ms,  elapsed time = 3293 ms.

And on second:
Table 'Table'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7581, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 5467, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1155 ms,  elapsed time = 7578 ms.

Thank you for your time, any suggestion ?

Comment: @JodyT I tried to run queries with different MAXDOP (1, 4,  8) and there are no changes.

Comment: @dean It is rented VM from hosting provider.

Comment: Looking at the statistics info, there's no physical reads at all (so it's not the storage, at least not here), CPU time is double (regardless of DOP), and so is the overall time. Look for the sort and hash warnings in default trace (to see if there's some problem with memory). I'd say that the VM is misconfigured, and you should engage the provider to check. It's hard to say anything more w/out seeing the host.